# Issue Building a Angular Project

Tags: angular

### I have been having several issues with angular missing modules
This is the issue i get

```
 Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\C#\JokeSaver\joke- 
 app\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?
```

protocol=auto%3A&username=&password=&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=0&pathname=%2Fws&logging=info&rec
onnect=10' in 'D:\C#\JokeSaver\joke-app'

Also I get when creating a new component

```
./src/app/home/home.component.ts-1.css? 
ngResource!=!./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loaders/inline- 
resource.js!../../../C#/JokeSaver/joke-app/src/app/home/home.component.ts:1:0 - Error: 
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
```

---

```
  [enter i[enter image description here][1]mage description here][1]
```

---

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.3
Node: 16.14.2
Package Manager: npm 8.7.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.3.3
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
```

---

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.3
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.3
@schematics/angular             13.3.3
rxjs                            7.5.5
typescript                      4.6.3


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQy8P.png







 I cant figure it out

 I have tried deleting node modules and reinstalling 

 Thanks
```

Comment: Please share a [min reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you also try to remove package-lock.json and node_modules, than reinstalling it?

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting these errors if one or more imports you have are not correct. Double-check all your imports, delete the package-lock and the node_module, and try again.